# Mi div se va hacia abajo

Tags: html5, div

Estoy iniciando en paginas web y el div se va hacia abajo eh probado reducir el height y de igual manera se va hacia abajo.
[image: Resultado][image: Es mi codigo de CSS]

[image: Mi codigo html]

Comment: Bienvenido. Por favor crea un [mre] y pon el código como texto.

Comment: Que es lo que quieres lograr conseguir con el codigo, si pudieras mostrar el resultado deseado te podriamos ayudar,quieres el div enmedio del negro, hacer 3 columnas pero no te deja, ponerlo encima del div blanco, no me queda en claro

Answer (score 0):

Te recomiendo evitar poner imágenes con código, ya que dificulta que algunos podamos recrear el código. Mejor cópialo y pégalo en formato de código o utiliza un snippet. Igualmente, trata de ser conciso en explicar la problemática y el resultado al que quieres allegar.

Lo que medio entiendo que quieres hacer es que dentro de un `div` deseas añadir más `div`, pero el problema es que no se acomodan según el contenedor padre. Esto es porque los divs se están comportando "por defecto" y se van poniendo uno abajo del otro.

Para manipularlos te sugiero utilizar flexbox y así se acomoden los items de manera flexible sin tanto dolor de cabeza. Te recomiendo una ojeada a [esta lectura](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Learn/CSS/CSS_layout/Flexbox) y [esta](https://www.w3schools.com/csS/css3_flexbox.asp) para que sepas cómo funciona.

Básicamente lo que debes hacer es asignarle a tu contenedor principal `display:flex` para que sus hijos se acomoden de manera flexible. Incluso puedes hacer que se distribuyan automáticamente sobre la misma fila o que si ya no caben, se vayan pasando abajo. Eso y muchas cosas más con flexbox. Así quedaría tu código:

```css
*{
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

div#Principal{
  display: flex;
  /*justify-content: space-around; *Si lo activas, los hijos se acomodarán a lo largo con un espacio**/
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 30px;
  width: 1900px;
  /*height: 850px; *Si le quitas el height al contenedo principal, su alto se ajustará según el alto máximo de sus hijos. */
  background-color: black;
}

div#nav{
  border-radius: 10px;
  width: 500px;
  height: 850px;
  background-color: aliceblue;
}

div#clase{
  width: 600px;
  height: 900px;
  background-color: aqua;
}

div#quienes{
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: red;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="Principal">
        <div id="nav"></div>
        <div id="clase"></div>
        <div id="quienes"></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Ahora bien, si no quieres usar flexbox, puedes usar `float: left` y quitarle el `position: absolute` para que se acomoden flotando a la izquierda uno tras otro (pero no te lo recomiendo porque te puede dar problemas a la larga, es mejor usar flexbox).

```css
*{
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
}

div#Principal{
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
  margin-top: 30px;
  width: 1900px;
  height: 850px;
  background-color: black;
}

div#nav{
  border-radius: 10px;
  width: 500px;
  height: 850px;
  background-color: aliceblue;
      float: left;
}

div#clase{
  /*margin-left: 511px;
      position: absolute;*/
  width: 600px;
  height: 900px;
  background-color: aqua;
      float: left;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="Principal">
        <div id="nav"></div>
        <div id="clase"></div>
        <div id="quienes"></div>
    </div>
    
</body>
</html>
```